# Scanner class do not take input properly

Tags: java

I am trying with user input to the values firstname, middlename, lastname, age for by using scanner class, but the below program only takes  firstname, middlename, lastname and not the value of age.

```
public void inputEmployeeDetails(){
     Scanner  scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                      System.out.println("Enter the firstname ");
                      firstname= scanner.nextLine();
                     System.out.println("Enter the middlename ");
                      middlename= scanner.nextLine();
                      System.out.println("Enter the lastname");
                      lastname= scanner.nextLine();
                     System.out.println("Enter the age"); 
                     age= scanner.nextInt();
     }
```

I need to take all the values one after the other through the user prompt.
Based on the entered data I am displaying the employee details. Could someone let me know what I am missing.

I would like to also like to take multiple inputs from the user. Please let me know if I am right in the below

```
 System.out.println("Do you like to fetch more records press "Yes" or "No");
       String input=scanner.nextLine();
       if(input="Yes")
       inputEmployeeDetails();
```

Comment: Please add expected and actual behaviour (the output or the error trace)

Comment: You should escape the quotes around Yes and No using a backslash

Comment: I unable to do it and the code for multiple inputs ain't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The age variable takes the next ENTER key that you press, so nothing is stored. Since the datatype of ENTER is different than the data type of age variable, hence your code was getting InputMismatchException. You need to check if the next value is an int then assign it to variable. Please refer below once:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
     public static void main(String []args){
     String firstname, middlename, lastname;
     int age;
     Scanner  scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the firstname ");
     firstname= scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter the middlename ");
     middlename= scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter the lastname");
     lastname= scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter the age"); 
     if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        age= scanner.nextInt();
     }else
        age = 0;
     System.out.println(firstname + " " + middlename + " " + lastname + " " + age); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The program terminates if I give  System.out.println("Do you like to fetch more records press Yes or No");
String input=scanner.nextLine();
if(input.equals("Yes\n"))
    inputEmployeeDetails();

Comment: I guess that was not part of this question. Can you please ellaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Check this program:

```
String firstname,middlename,lastname,choice;
        int age, flag;
        Scanner  scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
             choice=null;

         System.out.println("Enter the firstname ");
         firstname= scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the middlename ");
         middlename= scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter the lastname");
         lastname= scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the age");

        flag=0;age=0;

        while(flag==0){
        try{
        age= scanner.nextInt();
        flag=1;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Wrong entry, please enter digits only:");
        }
        }

        System.out.println(firstname+" "+middlename+" "+lastname+" "+age);

        System.out.println("Do you like to fetch more records press Yes or No");
        scanner.nextLine();   

                   choice=scanner.nextLine();
        }while(choice.contains("Y")||choice.contains("y"));                    

        System.out.println("Program terminated.");

        scanner.close();

        System.exit(0);
```